# Enviar Form de Modal no funciona

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas tardes. Tengo un problema a la hora de enviar por post los datos de un form que está dentro de un modal. Me explico.
Desde una tabla de exams.php llamo al modal pasándole el id del examen:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#message<?php echo $row['id_exam'];?>">Edit</button>
<?php include 'edit_exam_modal.php'; ?></td>
```

Cuando le damos al bóton nos abre el modal al cuaal le paso el id_exam. Hasta aquí todo funciona bien:
edit_exam_modal:

```
<div id="message<?php echo $row['id_exam'];?>" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

×

```
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Exam</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#111">
    <input type="hidden" name="idexam" value="<?php echo $papa; ?>">
    <label>Exam type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="examtype">
            <option><?php echo $row['type']."\n"; ?></option>
            <option>SAT 2016</option>
            <option>SAT</option>
            <option>SAT Subjects</option>
            <option>TOEFL</option>
            <option>ACT</option>
            <option>CLEP</option>
        </select>
    <label>Date</label>
    <input  name="examdate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="date" placeholder = "" required>

    <?php
    if ($type == "SAT") {?>

                <label>Critical reading:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['cr']; ?>" name="cr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Maths:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['mt']; ?>" name="mt1" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Writing:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['wr']; ?>" name="wr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">

    <?php   
    } elseif ($type == "TOEFL") {?>

                <label>TOEFL Score:</label>

                 <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['toefl']; ?>" name="tf1" id="focusedInput" type="float">

    <?php
    } elseif ($type == "CLEP") {?>    

                    <label>CLEP Score:</label>

                     <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['clep']; ?>" name="cl1" id="focusedInput" type="float">

    <?php
    } elseif ($type == "SAT Subjects") {?>

                <label>Subject 1:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['sb1']; ?>" name="sb11" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Subject 2:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['sb2']; ?>" name="sb21" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Subject 3:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['sb3']; ?>" name="sb31" id="focusedInput" type="float">

    <?php
    } elseif ($type == "SAT 2016") {?>

                <label>Reading & Writing:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['rw']; ?>" name="rw" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Maths:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['m']; ?>" name="m" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Essay Reading:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['er']; ?>" name="er" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Essay Analysis:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ea']; ?>" name="ea" id="focusedInput" type="float">



                <label>Essay Writing:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ew']; ?>" name="ew" id="focusedInput" type="float">


    <?php
    } elseif ($type == "ACT") {?>    

                    <label>ACT Score:</label>

                     <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['act']; ?>" name="ac1" id="focusedInput" type="float">


    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#111">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="update" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

llama a la página edit_exam_save.php y el boton de submit no funciona... Necesitaría ayudar para poder hacer el envio por favor.

Comment: no puedes enviar el formulario por ajax?

Comment: He probado algunos codigos que he encontrado por AJAX pero el problema lo tengo con el id del modal

Comment: cual es el problema con el id?

Comment: a la hora de hacer referencia al id del formulario en AJAX parece ser que no me lo coge... tendría algún ejemplo para hacer post por AJAX? gracias

Comment: @Vieira, en tu pregunta no veo cómo referencias el id del formulario. Por favor actualiza tu pregunta proporcionando mas información y si tu código genera errores.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta cambiar el tipo del boton, es decir por defecto si quieres que ese boton haga submit deberías especificarselo

```
<button type="submit" id="update" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

[Documentacion sobre los botones](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)